# Overlay a div over another and vertical align a text

Tags: html, css

I need to overlay a transparent div over another when I hover over an image inside a table td. This is working right now but it's a mess. Any way to improve the solution? 
The actual problem is that I need to vertical align a text inside this overlay div but I can't find a way to do it. So I made a script that the document is ready it calculates the margin top to align the text in the center. I feel like this solution is super ugly and also sometime it doesn't work and I need to reload the table.
Any help to vertical align this text using only css?
Thank you

HTML

```
<table id="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td id="xxx" class="fade-in">
                    <img src="...">
                    <a href="...">
                      <div class="over_text_container" id="xxx">
                        <p class="over_text">TEXT</p>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </td>
```

CSS

```
#table{
  display: table;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#table tr{
  min-width: 100%;
}

#table tr td{

  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;

}

#table tr td img{

  padding: 2%;
  padding-top: 0;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.over_text_container{

  padding: 2%;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.over_text_container:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #E3E6ED;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.over_text{
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: #7C7C7C;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
  user-select: none; /* Standard */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using flex:

```
.over_text_container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: #7C7C7C;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
  user-select: none; /* Standard */
}
```

Comment: uhm it seems to be working if I set these on the container, not the text. Thank you! Finally

Comment: @GiammarcoBoscaro If this solved your problem you should mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade yes, just correct it with .over_test_container instead of .over_text